# How to get the tick times that turtles arrive at different 10 patches using behaviourspace in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

There are 100 green patches and 10 turtles. Whenever a turtle comes to a green patch, it becomes red. So after a long time, all the green patches become red AT DIFFERENT TICK TIMES. I want to get those 100 different tick times to an excel sheet using `BehaviourSpace`. Also i want to run this 100 times. i.e I want 100 sets of 100 different tick times.

I have made a code such that when a turtle comes to the green patch, the patch becomes red and I have written "show ticks" under it. So when a green patch becomes red, the tick time is shown on command center at the bottom of the screen. Tick times Example: 34,56,78,98,99,...,1234. There are 100 different times.

```
breed [InfMosquitoes InfMosquito]

to setup
  clear-all

  set-default-shape InfMosquitoes "butterfly"
  create-InfMosquitoes  num-infected-mosquitoes-red
   [
    set color red
   ]

ask turtles [
    set size 1
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
     ]

ask turtles[
      ifelse coin-flip?
          [ifelse coin-flip? [set heading 0][set heading 90]]
          [ifelse coin-flip? [set heading 180][set heading 270]]
     ]

ask n-of num-humans patches [set pcolor green]

   show num-infected-mosquitoes-red

  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles
  [
          right random 360
          forward 1
      ask InfMosquitoes[
      if pcolor = green 
          [
            set pcolor red 
            show ticks   
          ]
       ]
  ]
    tick
end


to-report coin-flip?
  report random 2 = 0
end
```

I want to know what should I write in `BehaviourSpace` table. I know `Repititions:100`. I want to know what should I write on other command boxes.

Comment: Sir. My question is what should I write in command boxes in BehaviourSpace experiment window? What should I write in "stop condition" box? If i want the tick time that a green patch becomes red FIRST, then the stop code is " any? patches with [pcolor = red] ". But now I want to get all the 100 tick times that each green patch turns red, into a excel sheet. Hope my question is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable and initiate it as a list.

```
globals [
...
ticks-recorder
...
]

to setup
...
  set ticks-recorder []
...
end
```

Then, instead of having the tick number printed in the Command Center, you will have it added to the list:

```
to go
  ask turtles
  [
          right random 360
          forward 1
      ask InfMosquitoes[
      if pcolor = green 
          [
            set pcolor red 
            set ticks-recorder lput ticks ticks-recorder   ; this is the line I've changed
          ]
       ]
  ]
    tick
end
```

You will end up with `ticks-recorder` being a list of all the ticks when a patch changed colour to red.

Then, you can just specify `ticks-recorder` as a reporter in BehaviorSpace.

Note that, with this solution, you will end up with a list being reported. For example, let's say your list contains the values 1 and 2. In NetLogo, this is seen as `[1 2]`. This means that, if for instance you're opening your output file in Excel, the cell where your reporter is located will contain exactly the text `[1 2]`, which means that you won't be able to perform any mathematics on it.
You may or may not care about this, I don't know (e.g. you may be handling your output with a different programming language where you unlist the reporter).
But I think this becomes a different thing.